# "trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2"

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I'm trying to update and upgrade my kubuntu 15.04. After trying to install all upgrades, I got the following error message:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following packages will be upgraded:
kde-config-telepathy-accounts
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/122 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.948 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 626049 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1) over (0.9.0-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Well, it's saying that something it's trying to install is already installed and included in another package. This prevents it from finishing the installation. Run `sudo apt-get remove account-plugin-google` before trying again.

Comment: No known answer as yet. However, a bug report has been filed on Launchpad, which in turn has been propagated upstream. You can follow their statuses here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1451728 and here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347219

Comment: Same issue occurred when I try to install kubuntu and ubuntu 16.04 desktops.

Answer (score 16):

Deleting the conflicting packages works around the issue, until it is properly fixed.

```
sudo apt-get purge -f unity-scope-gdrive account-plugin-google account-plugin-facebook
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I saw `Alisson Silveira`'s answer, and it was close, but apt was still broken after that. The only way I found to fix it was:

```
sudo apt remove unity-scope-gdrive account-plugin-google account-plugin-facebook kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy
```

What a mess!

Comment: This worked for me too, where the other answers didn't.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by deleting *kde-telepathy* using Synaptic package manager, and now update and upgrade functions are working again.

Comment: Thank you! I had Synaptic installed and so could follow your advice!